# How to set Observable of type Object as a return value of method in interface

Tags: kotlin, observable, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to create a small example in kotlin using Retrofit as a practice in learnign Kotlin.
However, this line:

```
    Observable<Model.Result>//No type argument expected for class observable
```

please refer to the code posted below as well as the gradle file contents, and please let me know how fix this error.
i used the following link as reference to learn how to use Retrofit with Kotlin

**Object**:

```
public object Model {
data class Result(val query: Query)
data class Query(val searchinfo: SearchInfo)
data class SearchInfo(val totalhits: Int)
}
```

**WikiService**:

```
interface WikiApiService {
@GET("api.php")
fun hitCountCheck(@Query("action") action: String,
                  @Query("format") format: String,
                  @Query("list") list: String,
                  @Query("srsearch") srsearch: String):
        Observable<Model.Result>//No type argument expected for class observable


//why do we need a companion object
companion object {
    fun create(): WikiApiService {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(
                RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(
                GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/")
            .build()
        return retrofit.create(WikiApiService::class.
            java)
    }
}
}
```

**gradle**

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return Observable of type object from a method in the interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56950569/how-to-return-observable-of-type-object-from-a-method-in-the-interface)

Comment: check your imports, you're most likely using a different observable than the rx one.