# How to return Observable of type object from a method in the interface

Tags: android, kotlin, observable

I am learning kotlin. as shown in the code below, i created a object Model and an interface. the method in the interface should return

```
Model.Result
```

but when I wrap the aforementioned data type in Observable I receive the following error

```
No type argument expected for class observable
```

please let me know how fix this issue...as i tried to find some solution in google but it does not work

**Object**:

```
public object Model {
data class Result(val query: Query)
data class Query(val searchinfo: SearchInfo)
data class SearchInfo(val totalhits: Int)
}
```

**interface**:

```
interface WikiService {
fun method1(): Observable<Model.Result>//No type argument expected for class observable
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you show imports? 
You have probably imported wrong Observable class. I think you are using `RxJava2` so the import should be `import io.reactivex.Observable`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `java.util.Observable` that doesn't accept any paramter.

You should import `io.reactivex.Observable` that is parametrized.